# A clarification about Wallet and Addresses (In Armory)

Tags: transactions, wallet, blockchain, armory

I've just a dumb (Probably) question about bitcoin wallet and addresses (in Armory):

If I've understood correctly (Correct me If I'm wrong), a wallet works as a "container" where you can store different addresses (With their respective private keys). So for example, through Armory, I can create a wallet and inside the wallet I can create as many addresses as I want, right?

So, If I've created ten different addresses to receive payments, I just have to give one of the addresses (Of the wallet) to a person that has to send a payment to me. Let's say that I've received a payment of 1 BTC for each address; so I would have 10 BTC inside the wallet. When I want to send these 10 BTC to an X address, I just have to click on "Send Bitcoins" (then insert the requested data) and then Armory will send the 10 BTC (1 for each addresses) to the other address?

(BTW: Do I ever need to insert the bitcoin private key of an address to send a transaction, or I only need to insert the password for the wallet to be able to send the transaction?)

Therefore 10 different transactions would appear on the blockchain? (1 transaction for each Address that I have inside the wallet). And someone can know that these 10 transactions have been sent by the same wallet, or not?

Thanks in advance for any answer, as always :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct, the only thing that is incorrect is that there would be **only one transaction** that would be sourced with ten different inputs. You only have to input your password, you don't have to manually enter any private keys, unless you are importing new private keys to your wallet.

Since there would only be one transaction that would be accessing all ten addresses for inputs, the ten addresses would be known to be belonging to the same owner.

Also, strictly speaking the BTC aren't "in" the wallet: Rather, the wallet only contains the keys, while the BTC are stored decentrally on the blockchain. The BTC are "in the wallet" only in so far that they can be sent with the keys from the wallet, and that the wallet software keeps an account of what your balance is.

This results in the distinction that you only have to keep safe the keys to protect your spending power, the "history" part of your wallet is only for your information.